# Serverless framework AWS deployment error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I'm running into a weird error for which I can't find any documentation while deploying my aws lambda functions.
Aws lambda functions can't be deployed and is showing me this error

```
Error: Destination stack Versions is already full!
```

I'm using these 2 plugins for stack split:

```
- serverless-plugin-split-stacks
- serverless-plugin-additional-stacks
```

These are settings for split stacks & additional stacks :

```
additionalStacks:
    permanent:
      Resources:
        S3BucketData:
          Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
          Properties:
            BucketName: ${self:service}-data
  splitStacks:
    perFunction: true
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: false
```

It is inevitable splitting the services. The services are too big and I'm using stack split plugins so I wont exceed the resourse stack limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by disabling versioning

```
provider:
  versionFunctions: false
```

https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks/issues/15#issuecomment-610944852